# Internet Explorer Email Address Autolink -- Disable?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use a component called Codemirror for in-browser source code editing. It works great, but IE7 has a bug (feature?) that autolinks all email addresses that are typed into the code editing window.

For example, if I type `String x = "me@mydomain.com";`, IE turns this into `String x = me@mydomain.com;` -- it strips the quotes and underlines it.

Does anyone know how to override or disable this? Thank you.

-tjw

Comment: Is this problem just a visual one? That is, it doesn't affect the actual performance of the code?

Comment: It removes the quotes, which changes the syntax of the code... specifically, it makes the code invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard about Codemirror, but I did not used it yet, have you tried:

· Changing the @ for `&#64;`?

· Adding a part of the string to the other?

· Parsing the final result to String again?

Comment: the problem is that it happens immediately when it's typed. within a millisecond. this is a good idea though, I might be able to set up a listener and convert it before IE grabs it.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes instead of double should work. I've tested it in IE8 and IE9 RC1.

Comment: My post may have been misleading; the code that I'm writing is not javascript, I was just using that as an example. The language I'm using does not use single quotes for strings. That's a good piece of info though, thanks. I edited my post to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the component is using a Web Browser Control under the covers, which seems like an odd choice. You can prevent automatic hyperlink generation using ExecCommand(IDM_AUTOURLDETECT_MODE); see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893(v=vs.85).aspx

Prior to IE9, it was not possible to specify IDM_AUTOURLDETECT_MODE from JavaScript, meaning that pages could not disable automatic hyperlinking in ContentEditable areas. A new command constant AutoUrlDetect is supported in IE9, allowing script to disable automatic hyperlinking as follows:  document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false)

Comment: This problem is in IE7; how exactly does this help me?

Comment: Sounds like the solution is to tell everyone to use IE9... except I might as well just tell them to use Chrome. For some reason Google didn't need 15 years to develop a browser that works. No, sorry, that doesn't fly.